# Java x64 & InstallCert.java & jssecacerts: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, windows, security, certificate, keystore

I have a custom java-based tool to ping a server on the specified port. The tool works fine on Windows 7 x86, but fails with the following error on Windows 7 x64 with Java x64:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Here are some details:

First of all, to ping this server, I saved its CA certificate. For that, I used the following tool:
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java

The result of this tool is jssecacerts file. I placed this file to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib\security
JAVA_HOME variable is defined: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77

Then, I used my tool to ping the server:

```
package CallNotificationService;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class CallNotificationService {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    { 

        String MyServ = args[0];
        String certificate = args[1];
        String certPassword = args[2];

        System.out.println(MyServ + " " + certificate + " " + certPassword);

        String notificationService = "https://" + MyServ + ":9443/available";

        URL url = new URL(notificationService);

        HostnameVerifier HostValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };      

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(HostValid);

        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory(new File(certificate), certPassword));


        BufferedReader intpam = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = intpam.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        intpam.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    public static SSLSocketFactory getFactory( File pKeyFile, String pKeyPassword ) throws Exception {


          KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
          KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

          InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
          keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
          keyInput.close();

          keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());

          SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
          context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
          return context.getSocketFactory();

    }

}
```

In the stderr, I have the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at CallNotificationService.CallNotificationService.main(CallNotificationService.java:48)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

I also tried to place jssecacerts to %USER_HOME\security\trusted.jssecacerts in accordance with the doc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html), but it didn't help.

**A note:** It **DOES** work if I specify -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts in my command line (in this case, jssecacerts is placed in the same folder with my jar-application).

**The question:** since this code works in x86, I guess this failure in x64 might be related to jssecacerts location or something like that. **What should I try to cope with this issue?** Is there any specific with jssecacerts location in x64?

Thanks,
Racoon